# Questions on my program about a point on a graph

Tags: java, math

I'm working on a program that allows a user to input an x and y. After the user inputs an x and y the program will display the two points as an ordered pair and tell the user what quadrant the point is in, if it's to the left or right of the y-axis and if the point is below or above the x-axis. Some examples of the output would include:

```
Enter x: 3.4
Enter y: -8.2
Point: (3.4, -8.2)
The point is below the x-axis.
The point is to the right of the y-axis.
The point lies in quadrant IV.
```

---

```
Enter x: 3
Enter y: 0
Point: (3, 0)
The point is on the x-axis.
The point is to the right of the y-axis.
```

---

```
Enter x: 0
Enter y: 0
Point: (0, 0)
The point is on the origin.
```

---

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Graph
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //declare variables
        int x;
        int y;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in); // set up scanner to read user inputs

        // prompt x and y
        System.out.print ("Enter x:");
        x = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.print ("Enter y:");
        y = reader.nextInt();

        //display point
        System.out.println("\nPoint: ("+x+","+y+")" );


        //determine where the point is on a graph
        if( x > 0 || x < 0 && y > 0 )
        System.out.println( "\nThe point is above the x-axis.");
            else
        if ( x > 0 || x < 0 && y < 0 )
            System.out.println( "\nThe point is below the x-axis.");


        if( x < 0 && y > 0 && y < 0 )
            System.out.println("\nThe point is to the left of the y-axis.");
        else
        if ( x > 0 && y > 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is to the right of the y-axis.");
        else
        if( x < 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.println( "\nThe point is in Quadrant III.");
        else
        if(x < 0 && y > 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is in Quadrant II.");
        else
        if ( x > 0 && y > 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is in Quadrant I.");
        else
        if ( x > 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is in Quadrant IV.");

        if ( x == 0 && y == 0)
            System.out.println( "\nThe point is at the origin.");
        if (y==0 && x < 0 || x > 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is on the x-axis.");
        else
        if ( x==0 && y < 0 || y > 0)
            System.out.println("\nThe point is on the y-axis.");
    }// end class
}
```

I would appreciate the help as I am kind of rust at using java, thanks! :)

Comment: What's your problem exactly? You need to fully describe your issue and post any relevant errors.

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh yeah i forgot to include that. Well when i compile it it says there's no errors, but when i run the program and type in (2,2) for example it gives me

point: (2,2)
the point is above the x-axis
the point is in quadrant I
the point is on the x-axis 

when i run (3,0)
the point is above the x-axis
the point is on the x-axis

it doesn't really work properly is what i'm trying to say

Comment: @jugo You should edit the question to add any additional information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow help file, which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming* questions, as opposed to providing tutorial, design or code review assistance. You're well capable of solving this problem yourself. Leave your code alone for an hour. Get something to eat. Read a book. Play a game. Then go back and you'll see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** You problem with the point `(3, 0)` (and in general) is that your qualification for if a point is above the x-axis should depend only on the `y coordinate`. However, your if check depends on the `x coordinate` and the `y coordinate`.

**Example:**

```
if( x > 0 || x < 0 && y > 0 )
    System.out.println( "\nThe point is above the x-axis.");
```

Here it first checks if `x > 0` for `(3, 0)`, this is true, so it says that the point is above the x-axis, even though the y-coordinate is not `> 0` and this check should fail. The `||` statement will not check both sides of the operator if the first expression is true.

**Solution:**
Change your code to only check the `x-coordinate` when you need to see where the point is relative to the `y-axis` and check the `y-coordinate` when you need to see where the point is relative to the `x-axis`

Here is how the code should be with comments explaining:

```
// The x coordinate does not affect if it is above or below the x-axis
// Only check to see what the y coordinate is here
if (y > 0 ) {
    System.out.println ( "\nThe point is above the x-axis.");
} else if (y < 0 ) {
    System.out.println ( "\nThe point is below the x-axis.");
} // Here you could also add a check to see if y == 0, the it is on the x-axis

// Similarly, the y coordinate has nothing to do with what side of the
// y-axis the point is. Check only the x coordinate here.
if( x < 0 )
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is to the left of the y-axis.");
else if ( x > 0 && y > 0 && y < 0)
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is to the right of the y-axis.");

// According to your example desired output, this if-else block should be
// separate from the one above because you always want one of these lines to
// print  
if( x < 0 && y < 0)
    System.out.println ( "\nThe point is in Quadrant III.");
else if(x < 0 && y > 0)
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is in Quadrant II.");
else if ( x > 0 && y > 0)
    System.out.println( "\nThe point is in Quadrant I.");
else if ( x > 0 && y < 0)
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is in Quadrant IV.");

if ( x == 0 && y == 0)
    System.out.println ( "\nThe point is at the origin.");
// Again no need to check x here
if (y==0)
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is on the x-axis.");
// Again no need to check y here
else if (x==0)
    System.out.println ("\nThe point is on the y-axis.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the error in your code. Your if statements to find the location of the points are incorrect. You have this in one of them:

```
if( x > 0 || x < 0 && y > 0 )
```

All you need in your if statement is

```
if(y > 0)
```

because if y > 0, the point is above the x-axis regardless of what the value of x is. So, your if statements should look like this:

```
if(x > 0) System.out.println("The point is above the y-axis.");
else if(x < 0) System.out.println("The point is below the y-xis.");
if(y > 0) System.out.println("The point is above the x-axis.");
else if(y < 0) System.out.println("The point is below the x-axis.");
if(x == 0) System.out.println("The point is on the y-axis.");
if(y == 0) System.out.println("The point is on the x-axis.");
if(x == 0 && y == 0) System.out.println("The point is on the origin.");
```

Your code for the quadrants is correct, but remove the elses:

```
if( x < 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.println ( "\nThe point is in Quadrant III.");
if(x < 0 && y > 0)
            System.out.println ("\nThe point is in Quadrant II.");
if ( x > 0 && y > 0)
            System.out.println( "\nThe point is in Quadrant I.");
if ( x > 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.println ("\nThe point is in Quadrant IV.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if( x < 0 && y > 0 && y < 0 )
    System.out.println("\nThe point is to the left of the y-axis.");
```

and this

```
else if ( x > 0 && y > 0 && y < 0)
    System.out.println("\nThe point is to the right of the y-axis.");
```

will allways evaluate to false. `y` cannot be both `> 0` and `y < 0`